# Warning message when leaving your website to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you set up a warning message for any external links letting the user know that they are leaving your site and going to another?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a beforeunload function to do this:

**In Jquery**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

**In Javascript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Comment: weird its not firing when I click the link

Comment: does it work with _blank too?

Comment: @DavidBrierton No, it only runs when you are closing/leaving a page. Even if it is to the same site (or a refresh for that matter).

Comment: is it possible to do for the situation I stated?

Comment: @DavidBrierton Not with `beforeunload`. This answer does simply not answer your question.